# Create File Upload Progress Bar ASP.NET and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, file-upload

Any ideas how to create a very basic file upload progress?

It just needs to show the percentage of the file uploaded.

I've been seeing codes and plugins, but it looks very complex. I just want to try it out using WebForms to get the basics of it.

Answer (score 0):

Server-side is irrelevant, it's done entirely client-side.

The simplest method is available pre-packaged for you, found with just a little bit of googling, here: http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/