# how can I add a progress bar with showing percentage level while uploading file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create File Upload Progress Bar ASP.NET and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714858/create-file-upload-progress-bar-asp-net-and-javascript)

I have to create an web application in asp.net with C#.net in that i have to display progress bar to show uploading status of file how should i can do this?

Comment: What is the way you are using for uploading? Are you using `System.Net.WebClient` for example?

Comment: i am uploading file using asp.net file upload control

Answer (score 0):

what I had Understood from your question, based on that I had made an attempt to fulfill that using AJAX Extenstions.

My Code Here

```
    <div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/uploading.gif" />
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
    </div>

</div>
```

I Hope this Might Help You.
Please Mark as answer if It Helps You.

Comment: i want progress bar that showing progress status with percentage that how much file is uploaded

Comment: If You are Looking Progress Status with Percentage you have use some jquery Plugin which requires few jquery Knowledge. Check this Link. http://jquery.malsup.com/ or http://jquery.malsup.com/form/progress.html